# Occurrence of Characters

Tags: java, string, counter, indexof

I am trying to ignore Charakter which are not in the String Alphabet, but for some reason eclipse complains, that the Variable i cannot be resolved

Here is my Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class OccurenceOfCaracters {

```
static final int ASCII_SIZE = 256; 
static char getMaxOccuringChar(String str) 
{ 
    // Create array to keep the count of individual 
    // characters and initialize the array as 0 
    int count[] = new int[ASCII_SIZE]; 
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int charCheck;
    // Construct character count array from the input 
    // string. 
    int len = str.length(); 
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) 
        charCheck = alphabet.indexOf(str.charAt(i));
        if(charCheck != -1) {
            count[str.charAt(i)]++;  //Problem occurs here 
        }
    int max = -1;  // Initialize max count 
    char result = ' ';   // Initialize result 

    // Traversing through the string and maintaining 
    // the count of each character 
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        if (max < count[str.charAt(i)]) { 
            max = count[str.charAt(i)]; 
            result = str.charAt(i); 
        } 
    } 

    return result; 
} 


public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Text: ");
    String str = sc.nextLine(); 
    str =  str.replaceAll("\\s","").toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("Max. character is " + 
                        getMaxOccuringChar(str)); 
}
```

}

Comment: Try printing `(int) str.charAt(i)`.

Comment: When using Eclipse, configure your *Save Actions* to auto-indent your code. Then you'll see at once, that your problematic statement is out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problems is the loop.  This is from your code.  Note the `i` is local to the for loop but you didn't use {} so it isn't seen later when you use it to help index `count`

```java
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
         charCheck = alphabet.indexOf(str.charAt(i));
      if (charCheck != -1) {
         count[str.charAt(i)]++; // Problem occurs here
      }
```

Comment: That's one issue.

Comment: Yep.  Didn't convert the char to an int.

Comment: But if I cast the result from char to int and return a int, won't there be a error because the method is char and it returns a int

Comment: @Kirby_Sike  The other problem is that you were using a `char` as an `index`.  So consider the char  '1'.  That integer value is decimal `49` because it is a character.  The suggestion by `Andy Turner` to cast it was just for printing to show you the actual value instead of the character which would just show a digit.  In your case you need to convert '1' to 1 to use it as an index. Same for other digits.

Comment: @Kirby_Sike  BTW, char values are treated as ints and can be manipulated as ints. Casting is primarily used to display them as ints as opposed to characters (assuming I wasn't clear in my previous comment).

Comment: Thank you for your Help